# Add slash to the end of every url (need rewrite rule for nginx)

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I try to get an `/` to every urls end:

```
example.com/art
```

should

```
example.com/art/
```

I use `nginx` as webserver.

I need the rewrite rule for this..

For better understanding check this:

http://3much.schnickschnack.info/art/projekte

If u press on a small thumbnail under the big picture it reloads and shows this url:

http://3much.schnickschnack.info/art/projekte/#0

If i now have a slash on all urls (on the end) it would work without a reload of the site.

Right now i have this settings in nginx-http.conf:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name 3much.schnickschnack.info;
  access_log /data/plone/deamon/var/log/main-plone-access.log;
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /VirtualHostBase/http/3much.schnickschnack.info:80/2much/VirtualHostRoot/$1 last;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://cache;
  }
}
```

How do I configure nginx to add a slash? (I think i should a rewrite rule?)

Comment: Um... why would you want a / at th eend of all your URLs?

Comment: I need it for a js gallery. If there is no "/" it reloads the site...

Comment: I need the rewrite rule for nginx....

Comment: So the question is "How do I configure nginx to add a slash?"  Or is it "How do I configure nginx to work without a slash?"

Comment: Question should: How do I configure nginx to add a slash?

Answer (score 143):

More likely I think you would want something like this:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

The Regular Expression translates to:
 "rewrite all URIs without any '.' in them that don't end with a '/' to the URI + '/'"
Or simply:
"If the URI doesn't have a period and does not end with a slash, add a slash to the end"

The reason for only rewriting URI's without dots in them makes it so any file with a file extension doesn't get rewritten.  For example your images, css, javascript, etc and prevent possible redirect loops if using some php framework that does its own rewrites also

Another common rewrite to accompany this would be:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*)$ /index.php;
```

This very simply rewrites all URI's that don't have periods in them to your index.php (or whatever file you would execute your controller from).

Comment: This is the only post on the interwebs that doesn't add a trailing slash to EVERYTHING.  thanks for posting.

Comment: this one works much more reliably particularly with php frameworks that do there own pretty link rewriting

Comment: I have static html files so this: **http://domain.com/about** gets the file **http://domain.com/about.html** but still shows the URL without ".html". 
 
I am looking to add a slash after I hit the file but get a 404 now if I add a slash. So I want to remove the trailing slash (if exists) and with or without trailing slash gets "-html" file but shows "/" after. This does not work:

``rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1.html;
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;``

Also for click on "about" in a menu severa times I get this **http://domain.com/about/about/about/** etc..

Comment: What about query strings?

Comment: @EtienneMartin It looks like it will rewrite `domain.com/page?thing=abc` into `domain.com/page?thing=abc/`. Or does nginx detect and handle query strings separately?

Comment: @Benubird Yes I thought the same when I saw it but it tested it and it looks like query strings are handled separately.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong here, but unfortunately this seems to break down when working with nested directories. I don't have nginx so I'm just testing it against https://regex101.com/ so removing the beginning of line condition to operate on the full URL `http://example.com/foo/bar`, the pattern `[^.]*[^/]$`
matches `com/foo/bar`.
`\/\w+[^.][^/]$` on the other hand, matches `/bar` but not `/bar.html` or `/bar/`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if the URL contains a port: http://localhost:8080/something turns into http://localhost/something :T

Comment: For those getting the port added to the URL, try with `port_in_redirect off;` in your config file, it worked for me.

Answer (score 35):

```
rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

to avoid querystrings of a rest url getting a / tagged on.

e.g.

/myrest/do?d=12345

Comment: how could you make the result
```
/myrest/do/?d=12345
```

Comment: @PatrickLeeScott Adding '?' to regex to exclude would be sufficient I think

Comment: @PatrickLeeScott I'd added an answer that case

Answer (score 7):

For nginx:

```
rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

Comment: This will add a slash to EVERYTHING - so you'll end up with index.php -> index.php/, and page?a=b -> page?a=b/ where what the OP surely wants is page?a=b -> page/?a=b

Answer (score 6):

Odd that this is the first result in Google, but doesn't have a satisfactory answer. There are two good ways to do this I know of. The first is to straight-up check if the request will hit a file and only apply a rewrite condition if not. E.g.

```
server {
   # ...
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
     rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
   }
   location / {
      # CMS logic, e.g. try_files $uri $uri /index.php$request_uri;
   }
   # ...
}
```

The second, which many prefer as they'd rather avoid any use of *if* that isn't 100% necessary, is to use try_files to send the request to a named location block when it won't hit a file. E.g.

```
server {
   # ...
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @cms;
   }
   location @cms {
      rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
      # CMS logic, e.g. rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;
   }
   # ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it's too late but I want to share my solution, I've met issue with trailing slash and nginx.

```
#case : 
# 1. abc.com/xyz  => abc.com/xyz/
# 2. abc.com/xyz/ => abc.com/xyz/
# 3. abc.com/xyz?123&how=towork => abc.com/xyz/?123&how=towork
# 4. abc.com/xyz/?123&ho=towork => abc.com/xyz/?123&how=towork
```

and this is my solution

```
server { 
    ....
    # check if request isn't static file
    if ($request_filename !~* .(gif|html|jpe?g|png|json|ico|js|css|flv|swf|pdf|xml)$ ) {
       rewrite (^[^?]+[^/?])([^/]*)$ $1/$2 permanent;
    }
    ....
    location / {
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like your solution. It helped me :). It can be also imporved with a more gneric regex for file matching:   
`if ($request_filename !~* .[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ )`

This should match any file.

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    # ... omissis ...

    # put this before your locations
    rewrite ^(/.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    # ... omissis ...
}
```

If you want some kind of requests (say other than `GET` ones) to be prevented from doing this (usually it's about `POST` requests, as `rewrite` turns any request method into `GET`, which may break some of your site's dynamic functionality), add an `if` clause:

```
server {
    # ... omissis ...

    # put this before your locations
    if ($request_method = "GET" ) {
        rewrite ^(/.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    }

    # ... omissis ...
}
```

You can also put the `rewrite` in a `location` block (`if` too), to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

using the rewrites from anthonysomerset in a Wordpress, I experimented problems accesing to /wp-admin dashboard due to reirection loop. But i solve this problem using the above conditional:

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^/wp-admin")
{
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
rewrite ^([^.]*)$ /index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If nginx behind proxy with https, this  snippet do correct redirect for `$scheme`

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $upstream_scheme {
    "https" "https";
    default "http";
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $upstream_scheme://$http_host$1/ permanent;
    }
    ...
}
```

And on the upstream proxy pass the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header like:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule solves query string case too:

```
location ~ ^/([^.]*[^/])$ {
  if ($query_string) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/$1/?$query_string;
  }
  return 301 $scheme://$host/$1/;
}
```

> The regex has taken from `@marc`'s answer:
> `rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`

> The extra slash `^/` in regex is added to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ {
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

just add this

Answer (score -4):

Try this: `^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]`

This redirects (Status code 301) everything ($1) without a "/" to "$1/"

Comment: Gomez: You should absolutely 301 (redirect) the non-slashed URL to the slashed one, or search-engines and such will see example.com/blah and example.com/blah/ as two completely separate pages

Comment: I just tested this. ^(.*)$ redirects everything regardless. I had to use ^(.*)[^/] instead, so it only redirects if there's no ending slash.

Comment: This answer appears to provide syntax for Apache, but the original question is for nginx.