# Nginx isn't liking rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a site that uses subdirectories and currently only works when the trailing slash is added to the URL ("http://www.domain.com/dir/"). When there is no trailing slash, I get "unable to connect at server domain.com:8080" (8080 is the listening port Nginx is set up for).

I've tried adding the rewrite suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645853/add-slash-to-the-end-of-every-url-need-rewrite-rule-for-nginx) (and [here](http://www.osbmedia.com/blog/view/adding-a-trailing-slash-to-your-urls-on-nginx)), but it results in the "cannot connect" error for the entire virtual host.

Is there another way to add the trailing slash that I could try? Or, is there a way I can configure it to see the URL as a directory (and thus, look for the index file), regardless of the presence of the trailing slash?

*Edit*

Nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    map $scheme $fastcgi_https { ## Detect when HTTPS is used
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Server block:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        include www.inc;

        root /var/vhosts/domain/current/frontend/;
        include php.inc;
}
```

Php.inc:

```
index index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #fastcgi_param  ENVIRONMENT production;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 10;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 15;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

www.inc:

```
if ($host ~ ^([^\.]+\.com)) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.$host/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Please add server { } config where rewrite doesn't work.

Comment: Added, as well as the includes. I just thought - is the www rewrite the problem? If so, I could modify it to add the slash there, but would it work for URLs that are already including www? Is there a better way to modify it? I need the www check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change server {} block to

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    port_in_redirect off;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com; #Order matters!
    include www.inc;

    root /var/vhosts/domain/current/frontend/;
    include php.inc;
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. I tried just editing the rewrite line itself, since the server is hosting a number of different sites (so I have to be careful). I also tried replacing the include call in sites-available itself with your suggestion and still nothing. Would your suggestion even work if the URL is something like "http://www.domain.com/dir"? It would seem to me that it'd only work for "domain.com/dir".

Comment: @Shauna, I finally got it. Your server listens on non-standard port so redirection must include $server_port. See updated version.

Comment: Nope. "Cannot establish a connection at domain.com:8080". With the "default" (ie - the one I use for the other sites) setup, it already goes to port 8080, FWIW.

Comment: In theory. Unfortunately, in practice, that's not happening. =/

Comment: @Shauna, what exactly request you're making? Are you really have only one location {} block?

Comment: What I've provided is exactly what I'm using (I'm open to optimization suggestions, I inherited this stuff). As for the calls, now that this site/app are officially live, here's the live, working URL (and what I want it to go to): http://www.duethealth.com/ohiohealth/ ... Here's a few of the permutations that I've tried: http://www.duethealth.com/ohiohealth http://duethealth.com/ohiohealth duethealth.com/ohiohealth

Comment: @Shauna, your server doesn't allow connect to port 8080. It's normal as you're using Varnish. See updated answer.

Comment: Your suggestion for the www.inc doesn't work (results in "server isn't redirecting properly" error), but using the default www.inc, switching the server_name list, and adding `port_in_redirect off` did work! Thank you so much! And thank you for all the time you've spent helping. :D

Comment: @Shauna, don't forget to look http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name_in_redirect directive for understand why server_name order is important.