# Handle POST request in Grails without a path

Tags: grails, path, url-mapping

I have a requirement to handle an application that is POSTing XML to a server and port.  Unfortunately it is not possible for me to specify a path from this application and no way for me to change it.

So in Wireshark I can see it POSTing to

```
http://10.0.126.11:8082   <--- note the lack of trailing slash
```

If I set a test POST as follows in wfetch, I can route it just fine in grails.  The following is what shows in Wireshare:

```
http://10.0.126.11:8082/   <--- trailing slash
```

I have the grails setup to route setup for the root path "/" in the UrlMappings and have setup the grails.app.context = "/" in the Config.groovy.  Note that things just go badly if these are set to empty string.

Is there a way to go a step above the root path and respond to anything on the server:port?  Can Grails respond to a request without a path?

This is the situation I'm trying to handle when recreating with wfetch (note that there is no path):
[image]

Comment: Instead of posting directly to Grails, can you intercept calls to `http://10.0.126.11:8082` and forward to `http://10.0.126.11:8082/` using a proxy or perhaps a router-level rule?

Comment: @raffian, ya had thought of doing it that way but it seemed that I'd have to write some kind of proxy, that I was hoping to not have to do for a POC.  Do you know of any quick and dirty ways I could set up?

Comment: Check out nginx and other related http proxies, you don't have to implement one!

Comment: Good call, it looks like this could be a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792053/311525

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to play with the rewrite syntax, but I suspect it will work, good luck