# proxy_pass in nginx to publish webapp under a different directory

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have this location element:

```
location ~* ^/publicapp {
    proxy_pass https://myserver.domain.local;
}
```

The server myserver.domain.local hosts a web application located under /myapp.
I want to make it publicly available via https://www.mywebsite.com/publicapp. How do I tell nginx to translate /myapp to /publicapp?
Please keep in mind that I use ~* to allow case-insensitivity. Thus, I cannot use a URI with proxy_pass.

Kind regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works using

```
rewrite ^/publicapp/(.*) /myapp/$1 break;
```

At least it does with my very simple application.
Now I have to figure out how to do proper link translation (sorry for using ISA Server/TMG terms, don't know if it's the same in nginx).

Thanks to pythagor :-)

*edit*:

Works only if I keep a trailing slash after the url in the browser (https://www.mywebsite.com/publicapp/).

*another edit*:

To make sure URLs end with a slash:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

Taken from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645853/add-slash-to-the-end-of-every-url-need-rewrite-rule-for-nginx) (first answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~* /publicapp/ {
    rewrite ^/publicapp/(.*)$ /myapp/$1 break;
    proxy_pass https://myserver.domain.local;
}
```

This will rewrite your path and use new one at the .local server.

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes nginx request /old on myserver.domain.local.

Comment: Have you any rewrete rules at the myserver.domain.local? As you can see we have not `/old` here.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant /publicapp.