# add nginx virtual host

Tags: regex, nginx

I currently have the location alex/ available for users:

```
location ~* ^/alex/ {
rewrite ^/alex(/.*)$ $1 break;
```

I need to

> 1. add a new location, `/alexandru`;
> 2. make a permanent redirect from `example.com/alex` to `example.com/alex/`.

I have created the new location with `location /alexandru` and it works well, but when i try to use `rewrite ^/alex(.*)/$ /$1 break;` for the permanent redirect it fails.

Comment: Do you understand what `break` does?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3912675/5606054

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty solution:

```
location /alex {
   rewrite ^/alex(.*) http://$server_name/url_to/alexandru$1 permanent;
 }
```