# NGINX Force Trailing Slash (GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, laravel-5, url-rewriting, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to route all the URL to trailing slashes in Google App Engine (nginx server)

I have an Angular-Laravel 5.0 app. By default I am routing all the request to index.php which is located in `public/app/` dir so for that I have below rules

This is how my `nginx-app.conf` looks like

```
location / {
  index index.php index.html index.html index.js, index.shtml;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

This is how my `app.yaml` looks like

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
```

This is what I have in `app/Http/routes.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/app/');
});
```

My issue is

When I am visiting my site through URL `https://project-id.appspot.com/app/` it is redirecting me to `https://project-id.appspot.com/app/#/access/signin` but if I tried with

- `https://project-id.appspot.com/`
- `https://project-id.appspot.com`
- `https://project-id.appspot.com/app`

it is redirecting me to `http://project-id.appspot.com:8080/app/` **not to** `https://project-id.appspot.com/app/`

I have google regarding this and found out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912675/5019802), but I do not know how to use it with my existing rules.

I'll highly appreciate if someone can guide me.

*Please Note: I'm pretty new in nginx server*

Thanks in advance.