# Setup nginx-ingress to match two paths to the same serviceName and servicePort

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

**What I'm trying to do**

- Traffic to `/` needs to go to the FE `client` running on `3000`.
- Traffic to `/api` needs to go to the BE `server`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api?/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
```

**The problem**

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

- Fetches to `/api/auth` work fine.
- Fetches to `/api/admin` do not. Django removes the `/api` from the URL making it just `/admin` which doesn't exist. **This seems to be the default behavior of Django. As far as I can tell there is no way to override it.**

**What does work**

```
- path: /?(.*)
  backend:
    serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
    servicePort: 5000
```

- Navigating to `/admin` works fine.
- However, this removes the ability for traffic to be routed to the `client`.

Somehow, I need to prevent Django from stripping off the prefix. Or maybe there is a way to handle this type of routing from `nginx-ingress`.

**What doesn't work**

Any variation of the following:

```
- http:
    paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /api?/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /admin?/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 5000
```

---

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

---

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('', admin.site.urls),
]
```

---

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('api/admin/', admin.site.urls), # this justmakes it /api/api/admin given the ingress
]
```

---

```
# This just makes the URL pattern:
# - /api/api/auth/
# - /api/api/admin/
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include([
        path('auth/', include('authentication.urls'), name='auth'),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ])),
]
```

---

**Question**

So not quite sure how to resolve this.

- Is there a way to resolve this via `nginx-ingress`? Somehow strip off the `/api` after the request is submitted?
- Is there a way to prevent the default behavior of Django that strips `/api` off of `/api/admin`?

Comment: Have you tried to reach Django admin site adding [trailing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645853/add-slash-to-the-end-of-every-url-need-rewrite-rule-for-nginx) slash to the origin URL: `/api/admin/`? I had a problem like this in the similar user case, figured out that Nginx engine by invoking rewrite operation prevents load some specific content followed `/` root sub-path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following to the Django settings.py:

```
 FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/api/'
```

Update the STATIC_URL because it will no longer serve the assets for the admin portal:

```
 STATIC_URL = '/api/static/`
```